# finite simple groups and free groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, free-groups, simple-groups

It is well known that any group is a homomorphic image of a free group.
I want to know more about this theorem when $G$ is a finite simple group.
Does there exist any reference to state about it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The phrase you should look up is group presentations.

Comment: I think the question is too broad or too vague. You need to say more precisely what you would like to know. There is a lot of literature on presentations of the finite simple groups.

Comment: The kernel is maximal of finite index?... I wonder what happens when you intersect all possible kernels for all such groups...hmm...

Comment: I think this is a fact that "any finite simple group is generated by two elements, which one of them is an involution". I think there is a relationship between this fact and this question. Am I right?

Comment: Dear user1729, is it possible to explain your mean more? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment you added to your question, one relationship is that any group that is generated by $k$ elements is a homomorphic image of a free group of rank $k$. This is an immediate consequence of the [universal property for free groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group#Universal_property).